# Silverlight Toolkit Modifying October 2009 Source

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-toolkit

I have some changes I need to make to the Silverlight toolkit Charting source

I downloaded the Silverlight toolkit ... unzipped the source to a new directory

Added the 
Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit.csproj   Project to my Solution

Removed The reference in my silverlight application to 
    System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit
and Added
 A project Reference to  The Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit.csproj  Project

I then changed the  Legend.xaml 

to

> ```
> <Style TargetType="datavis:Legend">
>    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Lime"/>
>     <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
>     <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>     
>     <Setter Property="TitleStyle">
>         <Setter.Value>
>             <Style TargetType="datavis:Title">
>                 <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,5,0,10"/>
>                 <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
>                 <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
>             </Style>
>         </Setter.Value>
>     </Setter>
>     <Setter Property="Template">
>         <Setter.Value>
>             <ControlTemplate TargetType="datavis:Legend">
>                 <Border
>                     Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
>                     BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
>                     BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
>                     Padding="2">
>                     <Grid>
>                         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
>                             <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
>                             <RowDefinition/>
>                         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
>                         <datavis:Title
>                             Grid.Row="0"
>                             Content="{TemplateBinding Title}"
>                             Style="{TemplateBinding TitleStyle}"/>
>                             <TextBlock>Yeah</TextBlock>                      
>                     </Grid>
>                 </Border>
>             </ControlTemplate>
>         </Setter.Value>
>     </Setter>
> </Style>
> ```

Added a simple columnchart to my MainPage.xaml 

and Then ran it 
neither of the changes are visible in my Silverlight Page.

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Silverlight Toolkit uses some build tasks to move the control templates out of the seperate xaml files into the generic.xaml file. Since you probably don't have this build task (I think the team has made it available) you will need to make your changes in generic.xaml instead of Legend.xaml (or get the build task).

Comment: Correct. I previously blogged the DefaultStyleTask, and we shipped it in the November 2009 release - sorry that those files in the shipping source cause confusion.