# use Silverlight Toolkit custom build

Tags: silverlight, build, silverlight-toolkit

How do I use a custom build of the Silverlight Toolkit to build my Silverlight project?
I'd like to be able to step into Toolkit code while debugging.

Comment: I did quite the same as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681207/silverlight-toolkit-modifying-october-2009-source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the SourceCode tab and get the latest build for Toolkit.But you will have to reference Toolkit Project in you Working project to be able step into toolkit code while debug .

Here you can find latest builds list:
http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets

Comment: There are heaps of projects in the source and no instructions. But I guess the project you mention is Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit.csproj. What else is to do? Changing References to use the local Project as Reference. Anything else?

Comment: http://silverlight.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/network/Show?projectName=Silverlight&changeSetId=35261# 
Try get latest build from the above url. Archive should contain a structure like "Release->Silverlight3->Source" here you can find all the projects from Toolkit. Now it depends on your requirement whether you want all toolkit namespaces in you project or just some namespaces of it.